# MQ Depth triggering is working only first time

Tags: triggers, ibm-mq, depth

I have an MQ trigger defined on DEPTH as below. It triggers first time after creation, but does not trigger on again. The definitions are as follows.

```
DEFINE PROCESS(DEVL.OFFLOAD.PROCESS) APPLTYPE(UNIX) +
  APPLICID('/home/mqm/bin/queue_offload.ksh') +
  DESCR('Queue Offload Program Triggered on Depth')+
  replace

DEFINE QL('TEST.QUEUE') INITQ(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.INITIATION.QUEUE) +
   TRIGGER PROCESS(DEVL.OFFLOAD.PROCESS) +
   TRIGTYPE(DEPTH) TRIGDPTH(100) +
   replace

DEFINE SERVICE(SYSTEM.TRIGGER.MONITOR.SERVICE) +
   CONTROL(QMGR) SERVTYPE(SERVER) +
   STARTCMD('/usr/bin/runmqtrm') +
   STARTARG('-m +QMNAME+ -q SYSTEM.DEFAULT.INITIATION.QUEUE') +
   STOPCMD('/usr/mqm/bin/amqsstop') +
   STOPARG('-m +QMNAME+ -p +MQ_SERVER_PID+') +
   STDOUT('/home/mqm/temp/+QMNAME+_trm.out') +
   STDERR('/home/mqm/temp/+QMNAME+_trm.err') +
   DESCR('Trigger Monitor Service for Queue Offload') +
   replace

DISPLAY SERVICE(SYSTEM.TRIGGER.MONITOR.SERVICE)

START SERVICE(SYSTEM.TRIGGER.MONITOR.SERVICE)

DISPLAY SVSTATUS(SYSTEM.TRIGGER.MONITOR.SERVICE)
```

The queue_offload.ksh script disables trigger and enables GET, offloads messages from queue to a file, and at the end sets TRIGGER and disables GET on the TEST.QUEUE. With this setup, I first use the code above to create trigger setup, verify the definitions, then load the queue with 100+ messages, MQ triggers and executes the script, which successfully offloads queue and clears offloaded messages from queue, showing TEST.QUEUE curdepth of zero. After this first time, even with trigger monitor running, when I load 100+ more messages, MQ does not trigger and script is NOT executed. I tried with TEST.QUEUE GET enabled/disabled, and trigger/notrigger combinations at the end of the script. No combo made a difference. All the other conditions for triggering seems to be satisfied too. If I run the above code again to define trigger setup, it works one more time and stops triggering.

Am I missing something? What other settings could be tried?

Thanks in advance.

-BReddy

Answer (score 0):

The trigger monitor should be automatically setting queue to notrigger while it is processing and then back to trigger when done, I would not think your queue_offload.ksh needs to turn off trigger or get disable the queue.

What is output of "dis ql('TEST.QUEUE') all" and "dis qstatus('TEST.QUEUE') type(handle) all" after the second attempt to  put 100 messages on the queue?   Does it show queue set for trigger and get enabled? Does it show ipprocs and opprocs of processes connected?  Is the queue_offload.ksh disconnecting and releasing its connection to the queue after it processes the first 100 messages?

Comment: For Trigger type of Depth, the trigger monitor does not turn triggering back on - it is up to application to do it.  Also, I agree about the queue_offload.ksh script.

Comment: IPPROCS and OPPROCS are 0. This is a test queue, so nobody uses it, other than my test queue_offload.ksh which uses qload utility (MO03). The script disconnects after setting TRIGGER and GET(disabled). GET disabled so that (in production) nobody else gets these messages and accumulate until next time it trigger depth.

Answer (score 0):

After your application reads all of the messages from the queue, did you re-able triggering for 'TEST.QUEUE' via either MQSET (or alter qlocal)?

Comment: Yes. It does set the TRIGGER and GET(disabled) using alter qlocal.

Comment: When you initially define the queue it is not get(disabled) and it works then, right?  That may be your problem. What is in your trigger monitor output log?  Maybe it is triggering but can't get the messages because you have disabled it.

Comment: As I specified in first post, queue_offload.ksh enables the queue first, then offloads.